# access full object data set from within another class into the main class

Tags: php

I have searched hi and low for a solution to this without any luck whatsoever, so i posting as a last resort in hope someone can help me.

```
class Main
{
    private $data = array();

    private $a;
    private $b;

    function __contruct()
    {
    }

    public function a()
    {
        if (!is_object($this->a))
        {
            $this->a = new A();
        }

        return $this->a;

    }

    public function b()
    {
        if (!is_object($this->b))
        {
            $this->b = new B();
        }

        return $this->b;

    }

    protected function set_data($value)
    {
        $this->data = $value;
    }
}

class A extends Main
{
    function __contrust()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }

    public function test($value)
    {
        $this->set_data($value);

        return $this;
    }
}

class B extends Main
{
    function __contrust()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }

    public function test($value)
    {
        $this->set_data($value);

        return $this;
    }

    public function get_data()
    {
        print_r($this->a);
    }
}

$m = new Main();
$m->a()->test('add A class data');
$m->b()->test('add B class data');
$m->b()->get_data(); // want to use class A object data here
```

***edit***

```
[a:private] => A Object
        (
            [data:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => foo
                            [data] => 65
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => bar
                            [data] => 65
                        )
                )

            [a:private] => 
            [b:private] => 
        )
```

I have a method in the main class that finds the name key im looking for and returns its index so i can manipulate its data which works fine from its calling class. However class B needs to be able to set its own data back to the data array as well as get a hold of class A object data so i can manipulate its data.

So as you can see after i instantiate the main class and fire A class i want to be able to use the object data of A in my B class...

Would greatly appreciate any help possible.

Thanks,

Darren

Comment: It's hopefully easier for you to explain what you're trying to achieve with this, i.e. why you think you need this, than for us to explain what's wrong with it ;-)

Comment: Hi VolkerK... ill do my best to explain :) Basically i have the main class for setting / getting data etc then have 7 or so classes that extend off it each setting their own various data back into the main. Now one of those classes adds a name key for each data it creates into the main data array. So i need to be able to access this name key from the other class so i can update/add more elements to "its" array. Not sure if that makes sense or not otherwise i can edit the main post and provide more info?

Answer (score 0):

That's the code you may want:

```
class Main
    {
        private $data = array();

        protected $a;
        protected $b;

        function __construct()
        {
        }

        public function a()
        {
            if (!is_object($this->a))
            {
                $this->a = new A();
            }

            return $this->a;

        }

        public function b()
        {
            if (!is_object($this->b))
            {
                $this->b = new B();
            }

            return $this->b;

        }

        protected function set_data($value,$object)
        {
            $object->data = $value;
        }
    }

    class A extends Main
    {
        function __contruct()
        {
            parent::_construct();
        }

        public function test($value,$object)
        {
            $this->set_data($value,$object);

            return $this;
        }
    }

    class B extends Main
    {
        function __contruct()
        {
            parent::_construct();
        }

        public function test($value,$object)
        {
            $this->set_data($value,$object);

            return $this;
        }

        public function get_data()
        {
            print_r($this);
        }
    }

    $m = new Main();
    $m->a()->test('add A class data',$m->b());
    $m->b()->test('add B class data',$m->a());
    $m->b()->get_data(); // want to use class A object data here
```

and thats the output:

```
B Object
(
    [data:private] => add A class data
    [a:protected] =>
    [b:protected] =>
)
```

Comment: hi K102, thanks but not quite what im looking for as the data in objects A and B become reversed and would also mean all method chaining would have to pass the object parameter... $m->b()->test('add B class data',$m->a())->method('abc',$m->a())->method1('cde',$m->a()); which is not practical... but do appreciate the response